# Bash - combine 2 ssh calls into 1 (with optional and mandatory commands)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a script with 2 `ssh` commands.  The SSH scripts uses SSH to log into a remote server and deletes docker images.

```
ssh person@someserver.com 'set -x &&

   echo "Stop docker images" ;
   sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -a -q) ;
   sudo docker rmi -f $(sudo docker images -q) ;
   sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -a -q)'
```

Note use of `;` to separate commands (we don't care if one or more of the commands fail).

The 2nd `ssh` command uses SSH to log into the same server, grab a docker compose file and run docker.

```
ssh person@someserver.com 'set -x &&

   export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/somelocation/myaws.conf &&
   aws s3 cp s3://com.somebucket.somewhere/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml . --region us-east-1 &&

   echo "Get ECR login credentials and do a docker compose up" &&
   sudo $(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1) &&
   sudo /usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d'
```

Note use of `&&` to separate commands (this time we do care if one or more of the commands fail as we grab the exit code i.e  `exitCode=$?`).

I don't like the fact I have to split this into 2 so my question is can these 2 sections of bash commands be combined into a single SSH call (with both `;` and `&&` combinations)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh person@someserver.com 'set -x;

   echo "Stop docker images" ;
   sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -a -q) ;
   sudo docker rmi -f $(sudo docker images -q) ;
   sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -a -q) ;

   export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/somelocation/myaws.conf &&
   aws s3 cp s3://com.somebucket.somewhere/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml . --region us-east-1 &&

   echo "Get ECR login credentials and do a docker compose up" &&
   sudo $(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1) &&
   sudo /usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d'
```

Comment: This works, thank you.  In the future though I will use @Ruslan's suggestion of using a separate script as that makes more sense if they get bigger in size.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is possible to pass a set of commands as a simple single-quoted string, I wouldn't recommend that, because:

- internal quotation marks should be escaped
- it is difficult to read (and maintain!) a code that looks like a string in a text editor

I find it better to keep the scripts in separate files, then pass them to `ssh` as standard input:

```
cat script.sh | ssh -T user@host -- bash -s -
```

Execution of several scripts is done in the same way. Just concatenate more scripts:

```
cat a.sh b.sh | ssh -T user@host -- bash -s -
```

If you still want to use a string, use a [here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) instead:

```
ssh -T user@host -- <<'END_OF_COMMANDS'
# put your script here
END_OF_COMMANDS
```

Note the `-T` option. You don't need pseudo-terminal allocation for non-interactive scripts.

Comment: Thanks for reply - will use this in the future.

Comment: Another way to do this with: `ssh user@host 'bash -s' < script.sh`

Comment: @Zlemini, how about a couple of scripts?

Comment: For multiple scripts use a for loop, something like this: `for i in a.sh b.sh; do;  ssh user@host 'bash -s' < $i; done`

Comment: Or even simpler: `ssh user@host 'bash -s' < {a,b}.sh`